# Determine the clousure $\overline{G}$ of $G$ in $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Could someone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Let $G$ be the subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ defined by

$\left\lbrace
\begin{pmatrix} 
e^{2i\pi t} & 0 \\
       0    & e^{2i\pi\alpha t}
\end{pmatrix} : t\in\mathbb{R}
\right\rbrace$

Determine the clousure $\overline{G}$ of $G$ in $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$, where $\alpha$ is a irrational number.

Comment: This rather depends on what $\alpha$ is.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ meant to be an irrational number?

Comment: See [this page](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/shredding.shtml) on shredding the torus

Comment: yes, $\alpha$ is a irrational number.

Comment: I presume $\Bbb R$ should be $\Bbb C$ (twice)?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I presume that $\Bbb R$ still should be $\Bbb C$.